# Horrible Problems With 4K Video

Tags: windows-7, video, windows-media-player, 4k-resolution

Windows 7 is having a real issue with the 4k Video files I have. 
When I right click > properties > details, the frame height and width doesn't exist. Windows media player will only play audio, and VLC lags badly.
I finally ended up finding a player that could play 4K, but I'm curious why the files don't have height/width.

Even after rendering 4k from a video editor, the file details show nothing.

[image]

I should also mention that the icons have no thumbnail.

I'm kinda curious about all these problems but mostly about why the file details don't include Frame width/height. I think it's causing problems with windows media player reading it correctly, because WMP will only play audio.

Edit: For reference, I'm running a GTX 750Ti(2GB of VRAM) and an i5-2500k CPU @ 3.30GHz with 16GB of RAM.

Comment: So which player did you find? What sort of hardware do you have (CPU, GPU...)? Run MediaInfo on the file and paste the report so we can see what codecs the file uses.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the issues with playback is probably that your hardware doesn't support the 265 codecs directly, only some of the latest GPUs support that. If you do not have a high end system or one of the newer GPUs with direct 265 support I would recommend Media Player Classic - Home Cinema, it has much lower CPU usage than VLC or Windows Media player. I have no issues with playback in VLC on my main system with a 3930K but my media PC needs MPHC to keep the CPU usage low enough.

As for the length and height not showing up I am not 100% sure but I feel like that might just be an optional piece of information that just wasn't included in your particular files. I do not think it is related to the performance issues.

Comment: I'm running a GTX 750Ti with 16GB of RAM and an i5-2500k CPU @ 3.30GHz. I really didn't think hardware limitations would be an issue.

Comment: @meed96 - Provide documentation that your hardware does support the codec used by the video.

Comment: The 750Ti does support the H.265 codec but it was the first Nvidia card to support it and I have heard overall negative things about the hardware support. Since you have a decent CPU I would try specifically turning off the hardware acceleration and see if it works properly entirely running from your CPU. It probably should since I have not had any issues and my CPU is SandyBridge-E and the stock clock (Which I am not using currently but I did use for a stretch when I had to use a smaller PSU) is also 3.3ghz.

Comment: Where would I find the hardware acceleration settings?

Comment: That I am not totally sure on, I have an AMD card and it doesn't have H.265 acceleration. I think it might be in the settings of the media player you are using and not in the Nvidia drivers but I am not 100% sure of that.